# Identify JVM default timezone

Tags: java, jvm, timezone

Is there a way to identify the JVM's default time zone without running a Java program on it? Are there any commands available using which I can take a look at it?

Comment: JVMs don't run Java programs, they run bytecode, which may have been compiled from Java or any other of a number of languages. So, yes, you can do it without running a "Java" program, but you have to run *something*.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"default time zone"*?

Comment: @jotik the time zone of the JVM when you start it without setting the user.timezone property.

Comment: @Halley You mean like the contents of `/etc/timezone` when JVM starts up on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah we all know what jvm is , but maybe author want to know what is a default timzeone of running jvm without restarting it and deploying code on it.

In such case you could maybe check command line of java process for properties (user.timezone) or connect to jvm via some tool like visual vm and check this property, I am not sure if there is some other way to do that.

If you have remote debugging enabled then it should be easier as you can connect via your favourite ide/tool and just evaluate default timezone.